# $U=qV$: is my understanding right?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, ionization-energy

Suppose a point charge (q) moves from point A to point B, only under the influence of an external charge configuration.

**ΔU=qΔV**: The change of the potential energy of **the charge+external configuration system** is equal to q times **V(B)-V(a)**

**U=qV**: The potential energy of **the point charge** is equal to q times **the potential at the point charge’s location**

<**Additional info**>
This seems inconsistent (and counterintuitive since both should relate the potential energy of a **system** or **charge**; only one intuitively). However, this was the consequence of calculating values (U, V) in a simple situation I made up, using fixed two points as a *configuration* mentioned earlier.

Where am I wrong? Or is my understanding right?

Comment: Can this question have an explicit example with only two point charges? I don't get the inconsistency. From a math point of view if y(x)=c x then dy(x)=c dx

Comment: So my 'example' was about three charges- two of which are 'configuration' (the other one is a test charge). My reasoning was that, at a fixed point (where test charge is present), V(scalar field by the 'configuration')=k(q1/r1+q2/r2) but V*(charge of test charge) isn't equal to the potential energy (U=k(q1q/r1+q2q/r2+q1q2/r)) of three charges system. That was my point

Answer (score 0):

Potential, $V$, and potential energy, $U$, are two different things.

A way of describing a field is to use the concept of potentials.
For example, the **electric potential** at a point is the work done in bringing unit positive charge from an arbitrarily chosen zero of potential to that point.
Note that the unit positive charge does not contribute to the potential at the point.

**Electric potential energy** is the energy stored in a system of bodies by virtue of their charge and position relative to one another.

> $U=qV$: The potential energy of the point charge is equal to q times the potential at the point charge’s location.

A point charge cannot have potential energy as to use the concept of potential energy there must be at least two charges present.
Put another way, a single charge on its own cannot do work.
When you use this equation to find the electric potential energy of a system, the system is everything that has contributed to the potential at the position where $V$ has been evaluated **and** the charge $q$.
This is the same as your equation, $\Delta U= q\Delta V$, except that in this case the initial potential might not be zero.